# Serving requests in Spring Boot from multiple read DB replicas

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-rds, database-replication

We have a Spring boot which app talks to Postgres (AWS RDS).

I have 3 APIs and out of which 2 are PUT and one is GET.
GET is high velocity API i.e. QPS for GET is too high compared to first two APIs.

We are adding a two new Postgres Readonly Replicas which will be used by just GET API requests.PUTs will be served from primary.

How do I manage datasources for 1 primary and 2 replicas in Spring boot app?
Also how can we make sure GET requests are hitting replicas only and at the same time equally distributing load between two replicas. We want this to be future-proof as well i.e. if we new replica tomorrow then it should be just a configuration change specifying new replica data source url and GET should now distribute traffic among three replicas without any change.

What's best strategy to achieve this in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, RDS will provide you with a read/write URL and a read only URL. You will need to create two data sources, and call each one appropriately (i.e. use your read only datasource for select queries, and your read/write datasource for insert/update/delete queries)

In Spring Boot, the name of the @Bean method can be used to inject multiple beans of the same type, or you can use the `@Qualifier` annotation when injecting. so like

```
@Bean
fun readOnlyDataSource(): DataSource = ...

@Bean
fun readWriteDataSource(): DataSource = ...
```

And then to inject it

```
@Repository
class SomeComponent(
  private val readOnlyDataSource: DataSource,
  private val readWriteDataSource: DataSource
)
```

In your config you can set up multiple connections

```
spring:
  datasource:
    readonly:
      ...
    readwrite:
      ...
```

Although if you're using AWS it might be better to use spring cloud and parameter store to load in the RDS urls rather than putting them directly into the config.